# Calling PHP functions from Form Submit

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and I do not know how to do things properly and I need help

I have register-page.php which looks like this:

```
<?php include "includes/functions/Register/Register.php"?>
<?php include "includes/header.php"?>
<?php include "includes/navbar.php"?>
<?php include "includes/registerContainer.php"?>
<?php include "includes/hidden.php"?>
<?php include "includes/footer.php"?>
```

as you can see from the code above I have I'm keeping files in the includes folder and Register.php is the file that keeps the functions

the form in register-container.php:

```
<form action="" class="registerForm" method="post">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group regElements">
                            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            <input class="form-control " name="regEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group regElements">
                            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            <input class="form-control " name="regUsername"  type="text" placeholder="Username"  >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group regElements">
                            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                            <input class="form-control " name="regPassword"  type="password" placeholder="Password"  >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group regElements">
                            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
                            <input class="form-control " name="regPassword2"  type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="errors">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group regElements">
                            <input id="regButton" name="registerButton"type="submit" class="btn" value="Register Now!">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

as you can see I left the form action empty because my code works WHEN
I include this piece of code:`<?php include "includes/functions/Register/Register.php"?>`at the bottom (under footer)

but now I realised that by doing this I can't use Sessions, when I try I receive an error.

I do not know how to solve this issue if anyone can help me it is very much appreciated. If more information is needed by my side please let me know Thanks

EDIT: I have realised that when I place the register function on top it works but the function that Displays the errors does not which is

```
function errorDisplay($regErrors){
    //Display Errors
        foreach ($regErrors as $errrorMessage) {
            ?>
                <script>
                    $("#errors").append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><?php echo $errrorMessage; ?></div>');
                    if($(window).width()<=1024 && $(window).height()<=768){
                        $(".registerContainer").animate({marginBottom:"75vh"});
                    }
                    else{
                        $(".registerContainer").animate({marginBottom:"60"});
                    }
                    alert($msgheight);
                </script>
            <?php
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the error / issue is? Could you perhaps clarify?

Comment: When Register.php is at the most bottom I can register if I place it on top nothing happens. I do not receive any errors

Comment: I think the HTML is useless, but include `Register.php` in your question maybe usefull. I bet `session_start()` is at the top of `Register.php`. That why `$_SESSION` cant work if you include this file at the bottom. (`session_start()` must be the first thing declare in your code if you want to use it).

Comment: I edited my post, I have realised that because the php file is on top that has functions the function to display errors with jquery does not work, any suggestions?

Comment: maybe interesting? https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/146